# Who are these learned rishis mentioned in the Mahabharat?

Tags: mahabharata, rishi

The **[Anushasan Parva of Mahabharat](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b115.htm)** mentions many dignitaries that are praiseworthy and names a few rishis:

> After this I shall recite the names of those foremost Rishis who are known as Manavas. They are **Yavakrita, Raibhya, Arvavasu, Paravasu,** and **Aushija, Kakshivat,** and **Vala the son of Angiras**. Then comes **Kanwa** the son of the Rishi Medhatithi, and **Varishada**.

I found the stories of the first four [here](http://www.manuscrypts.com/myth/2010/09/22/arvavasu/) and know about Kanva, and Aushija seems to be another name of Kakshivat (since his mother was Ushija) so **I want to know more about the remaining rishis Vala and Varishada.**

If it is any help the text further states:

> They have sprung from Rudra and Anala and the Vasus. By reciting their names people obtain great benefits. Indeed, by doing good deeds on earth, people sport in joy in heaven, with the deities. These Rishis are the priests of Indra. They live in the east.

Comment: I have noticed that Sacred-text often uses letter V for B. Like Budha is Vudha, Brihaspati is mentioned as Vrihaspati. Probably Varishada is Barishada. Who was born in lineage of Prithu and was a Prajapati. https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/4/24/9

Answer (score 4):

Sanskrit verse of this section is following. You can refer them [here](https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/txt/mbh12.itx)

> yavakrIto.atha raibhyashcha arvAvasuparAvasU | aushijashchaiva
>   kakShIvAnnalashchA~NgirasaH sutAH || 25||
>
> RRiShermedhAtitheH putraH kaNvo **barhiShadastathA** |
>   trailokyabhAvanAstAta prAchyAM saptarShayastathA || 26||

As you can see, Varishada is actually Barhishada (who is Prajapati Barhishat or Prachinabarhi). Barhishat was born in lineage of Maharaja Prithu and is father of ten Prachetas. Details of Barhishat is given in Srimad Bhagvatam Canto 4 ([SB 4.24.9](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/4/24/9))

Comment: This is another verse from Shrimad Bhagwat Purana mentioning king Barhiṣat .- https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/4/25/1

Comment: Nice thanks for sharing. Any idea about the son of Angiras?